# Mysql character set and collations - UTF8mb4 520

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

Problem: mysqldump will not import due to missing collation

> ## 1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'

The Mysql server is (from phpMyAdmin):

```
Server version: 5.5.40 - MySQL Community 
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
Database client version: libmysql - 5.0.95
```

This is a centos 5.11 server.

```
mysql> show variables where Variable_name like 'character\_set\_%' or Variable_n                            ame like 'collation%';
+--------------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name            | Value           |
+--------------------------+-----------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8            |
| character_set_connection | utf8            |
| character_set_database   | utf8            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary          |
| character_set_results    | utf8            |
| character_set_server     | utf8            |
| character_set_system     | utf8            |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8_general_ci |
+--------------------------+-----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have local server (xampp) which has

```
> Server version: 10.1.9-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
> Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)  Database client version:
> libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id:
> 3c688b6bbc30d36af3ac34fdd4b7b5b787fe5555 $
```

This imports fine.
Looking at the final tables that are imported I see that the collation for all tables is utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
The same happens (i.e. as my local which imports correctly) when I upload to a public server

```
Server version: 5.6.29 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
```

**Why does my local database handle the 520 collation whereas the centos box does not?**

Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated. All uploads are performed via phpMyAdmin with the specs above.
I know I can 'update' the SQL dump and remove the '520' reference and just replace with utf8mb4_unicode_ci but if you have to do this every time it's not very economical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci was not introduced until MySQL 5.6 so the older 5.5 version on your CentOS box would explain why you don't have it.