# #1115 - Unknown character set error in Mysql

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have mysql version 8.20 on server and in local,I am using xampp which has mariadb

so while trying to import server db into local getting error like

```
#1115 - Unknown character set:
```

so tried to fix this using

```
sed -i dump.sql -e 's/utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g'
```

so it is creating another error for utf8mb4

instead of that, can I remove COLLATE from it and import?

Comment: *can I remove COLLATE from it and import?* This may cause data damage... *#1115 - Unknown character set:* What charset is unknown? to what MySQL (or MariaDB?) version? PS. utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci and utf8mb4_unicode_ci are collations, not charsets.

Comment: Please share more details, such that others can reproduce the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql character set and collations - UTF8mb4 520](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953312/mysql-character-set-and-collations-utf8mb4-520)

Answer (score 0):

It's worked with following commands:

```
sed -i dump.sql -e 's/utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/utf8_unicode_ci/g' 
sed -i dump.sql -e 's/utf8mb4/utf8/g' 
sed -i dump.sql -e 's/utf8mb4_general_ci/utf8_general_ci/g' 
sed -i dump.sql -e 's/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/utf8_unicode_ci/g' 
sed -i dump.sql -e 's/utf8mb4_tr_0900_ai_ci/utf8_unicode_ci/g' 
sed -i dump.sql -e 's/utf8_vi_0900_ai_ci/utf8_unicode_ci/g'
```

Comment: You know `sed` allow you to do multiple expressions in one invocation. `sed -i dump.sql -e ... -e ... -e ...` etc.

Comment: @BillKarwin I was not aware.

Comment: Can you add more explanation about what you found out the cause of error was and how the fix works? The first sed line contains the same command that is part of the question already which is part of the problem, and not part of the solution maybe?